# Trying to make an Ajax call to a web form method and getting an internal server error. I have tried almost all solutions to similar questions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, http

The function getClientData() gets called from one of the anchor tags in a grid's column. The anchor tag has a couple of Data-Tags which are passed to the code behind method. I have to perform some DB operation through these parameters but before that I wanted to make sure if this prototype would work.

This is how the anchor tag looks:

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="getClientData()" class="endec" data-kt="Cpuqsrtsotmfegrhsi-jikdbCvuwsxtcodmeelrmI-Dn-ovpcqSresctrfegthKiejy" data-kv="1p7q9">Show</a>
```

This is my Javascript method:

```
 function getClientData() {

            //var dataValue = { "keyData": this.event.target.getAttribute("data-kt"), "valueData":  this.event.target.getAttribute("data-kv")};

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Clients.aspx/GetClientData",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ keyData: this.event.target.getAttribute("data-kt"), valueData:  this.event.target.getAttribute("data-kv")}),
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.statusText);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Success: " + result );
                }
            });
        }
```

I put a break point here and it never gets triggered. This is my web method in the code behind file:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
    public string GetClientData(string keyData, string valueData)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyData) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueData))
        {
            result = "Decrypted String!";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is the URL that gets created for the POST request "http://localhost:60825/Clients.aspx/GetClientData?{%22keyData%22:%22Cpuqsrtsotmfegrhsi-jikdbCvuwsxtcodmeelrmI-Dn-ovpcqSresctrfegthKiejy%22,%22valueData%22:%221p7q9%22}". Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You're creating JSON and appending that directly to the URL. That means there's no `keyData` GET param. Your `data` and `dataType` options suggest you're supposed to send this as `type: "POST"`, maybe?

Comment: Thanks Chris. However, I tried issuing a GET request as well but that also doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Here's how to avoid inline code and examples of the GET and POST request: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/cdf5a3bj/

Comment: From what I guess, parameters get populated with the correct values. There's any other issues which is preventing this AJAX call to the WebMethod. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You can inspect the AJAX calls in the browser's dev tools. You can also narrow down the issue by making the calls with Postman to check if your server is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you configured routing but based on your API method (code behind) your data should be formatted in following manner:

**Method 1**:

`http://localhost:60825/Clients.aspx/GetClientData?keyData=Cpuqsrtsotmfegrhsi-jikdbCvuwsxtcodmeelrmI-Dn-ovpcqSresctrfegthKiejy&valueData=1p7q9`

As you can see, instead passing stringified JSON object I am sending data in format of query string where `keyData` and `valueData` has corresponding values.

**Method 2**:

If you prefer to send stringified JSON you can modify your Payload in URL like this:

```
http://localhost:60825/Clients.aspx/GetClientData?data=%7BkeyData%22%3A%22Cpuqsrtsotmfegrhsi-jikdbCvuwsxtcodmeelrmI-Dn-ovpcqSresctrfegthKiejy%22%2C%22valueData%22%3A%221p7q9%22%7D
```

Here I am sending stringified JSON as `data` parameter in query string. For that purpose your code behing method needs to be like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public string GetClientData(string data)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyData) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueData))
    {
        result = "Decrypted String!";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kat1330. I have tried my luck without the JSON.stringify() method and it doesn't produce different results either. The URL without stringifying the data looks like this:


http://localhost:60825/Clients.aspx/GetClientData?keyData=Coupsqtrosmtefrgsh-iijdkCbuvswtxocmdeerlImD--nvocpSqercsrteftgKheiy&valueData=1o7p9